# Como ejecutar este ejemplo?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Hola cuando le pongo la variable **@NUM** me arroja un error no puedo ejecutar la consulta:

```
ESTO es un TRIGER desdepues de X accion en tabla se deberia ejecutar un PROC

DECLARE @vTableName varchar (20) = 'TEST',@NUM INT =250
EXEC PROC ('PS_Gamelog.dbo.' + @vTableName + '')
@NUM
```

Esta es el Prose de Test.

```
USE [PS_GameLog]
GO
ALTER  Proc [dbo].[TEST]
@NUM varchar (12)
AS
PRINT 'Salida de dato Numero: (' + @NUM+ ') Exitosa.'
```

el error que recibo es:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@NUM'
```

Comment: En que parte del código te da el error?. Es después del ('PS_Gamelog.dbo.' + @vTableName + '') ?
Por que colocas el : "@NUM" en la ultima linea? que se supone que esta haciendo ahi?

Comment: Amigo es un TRIGER

Comment: Cual es tu intencion con la ultima lina de @NUM? Imprimirla? obtener su valor? asignarle valor?

Comment: Sea o no un trigger el : "@NUM" no debe estar ahí, al menos que sea un "OUTPUT" y este retorne un valor del PROCEDURE. si es es el caso, debería ir con un coma separando los parámetros,. por eso te preguntaba por que colocas el :"@NUM" en la ultima linea aparte? por eso obtienes el error: "Incorrect syntax near '@NUM'"

Comment: precisamente es un OUTPUT

Comment: Toma en cuenta lo que comente y trata de ponerlo mas completo el código así evitaremos suponer cosas..

Comment: Hermanito lo puse COMPLETO

Answer (score 0):

El [`PRINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) no evalúa, simplemente imprime un cadena literal o una variable, lo que buscas debes resolverlo previamente, así:

```
DECLARE @Mensaje VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT  @Mensaje = 'Salida de dato Numero: (' + @NUM + ') Exitosa.'

PRINT @Mensaje
```

Comment: No amigo no me sirve DIRECTO pues no quiero ser directo necesito que sea por Procedimiento almacenado amigo el trigrer ejecuta el procedure

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez no entiendo tu comentario. Según tu pregunta el problema es `Incorrect syntax near '@NUM'`, tal vez no se entendió mi respuesta, pero no puedes hacer la concatenación de variables en un `print`, eso es lo que intenté responderte.